# Unreachable if statement, how to avoid

Tags: qt, qml

I have this code in Qt 5.9.4:

```
ButtonStyle {
    padding.top: 0
    padding.bottom: 0
    padding.right: 0
    padding.left: 0
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: enableButton.height
        implicitWidth: enableButton.width
        color: {
            if ((buttonEnabled || hoverAlways) && enabled) {
                if (propertyButton.hovered)
                    hoveredBgColor
                else
                    defaultBgColor
            } else {
                selectedBgColor
            }
            if (propertyButton.pressed)
                selectedBgColor
        }
    }
}
```

I receive these warnings on Qt 5.11.2:

> Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor

The solution for the above warning is to use `return` statements like below:

```
ButtonStyle {
    padding.top: 0
    padding.bottom: 0
    padding.right: 0
    padding.left: 0
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: enableButton.height
        implicitWidth: enableButton.width
        color: {
            if ((buttonEnabled || hoverAlways) && enabled) {
                if (propertyButton.hovered)
                    return hoveredBgColor // return here
                else
                    return defaultBgColor // return here
            } else {
                return selectedBgColor // return here
            }
            if (propertyButton.pressed) // this condition is unreachable
                return selectedBgColor // return here
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the above `return` statements the warning is resolved, however the `if (propertyButton.pressed)` statement becomes unreachable. I wonder what is the best practice to avoid such unreachable conditions.

Comment: If you always want the color to be selectedBgColor in the case that propertyButton.pressed is true, then put that at the top of the block

Comment: @Ian I think your suggestion resolves my issue.

Comment: Good.  I'll add it as an answer then

Comment: @Ian Thanks! Accepted and up-voted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the use of return makes control leave the code block, the best practice is to ensure that all of your special cases are handled first.

In your case, move the last check up to the top of that block, e.g.:

```
ButtonStyle {
    padding.top: 0
    padding.bottom: 0
    padding.right: 0
    padding.left: 0
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: enableButton.height
        implicitWidth: enableButton.width
        color: {
            if (propertyButton.pressed) // moved up from below if-else block
                return selectedBgColor  //
            if ((buttonEnabled || hoverAlways) && enabled) {
                if (propertyButton.hovered)
                    return hoveredBgColor
                else
                    return defaultBgColor
            } else {
                return selectedBgColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```